# Remover ou não uma resposta mesmo dentro do contexto, depois de a pergunta ter mudado o sentido

Tags: debate, respostas

gostaria de saber se devo deletar minha resposta onde inicialmente a pergunta era (Quebra de linhas em um atributo data). Passado um dia após a resposta, a pessoa com a dúvida achou uma solução e eu indiquei que publicasse como resposta. Porém, eu percebi que na verdade a pergunta deveria ser diferente, assim eu editei e mudei o título para (**Quebra de linhas em um atributo data ao exibir no front-end**) Veja: [Quebra de linhas em um atributo data ao exibir no front-end](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/351597/quebra-de-linhas-em-um-atributo-data-ao-exibir-no-front-end).

É algo simples, mas veja a confusão. Não é um erro de interpretação, mas eu respondi o que foi perguntado. Sei que isso tudo poderia ser resolvido utilizando o campo comentário antes de responder, mas eu teria que prever o que o perguntador estava querendo. Algo diferente do que foi perguntado.

Com base na pergunta, olhando o código que no teste retornava:

`data-content=" 1<br>2<br>3<br>4<br>5<br>6<br>7"`

Então ao responder a pergunta (Quebra de linhas em um atributo data), a quebra foi feita:

```
data-content="
1
2
4
3
5
6
7"
```

Agora que tudo mudou, devido a mudança do título da pergunta. A **minha resposta** deve ser deletada ou eu não deveria ter **editado o título inicial** da pergunta? Visto que editei, logo após o próprio perguntador **responder** dia depois, exatamente para fazer sentido em relação ao que ele queria.

Estou confuso desde o começo. Como proceder da próxima vez?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sem entrar no mérito específico, em geral o mais correto é reverter a edição e quem sabe até fechar a pergunta como não clara. Se a pessoa fez uma pergunta e quer mudar depois que teve respostas está prejudicando quem se esforçou para responder o que estava ali. Pelo menos nos casos que parecia claro, mas a pergunta era toda enganosa. Quem cometeu o erro é que "merece algum tratamento excepcional", por isso a resposta não deveria ser apagada. Mas sempre tem que analisar cada caso, há situações que nem deveria ter respondido.

Quando eu vi essa pergunta eu quase fechei, apenas não o fiz por não ter certeza se era o melhor a se fazer. E agora parece que eu deveria ter feito, tudo ali está esquisito.

Comment: Concordo! Tudo ali está esquisito.